# chrome apps- content security policy - jquery datepicker() not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension

i tried this :

```
    <div id="d1"> sampletext </div>
    $("#d1").datepicker();
```

when i run above code, it is showing datepicker , but without any formatting like good background and others, why ? 
Also , after i click on any date in the date picker, getting the error

```
Refused to execute inline event handler because of Content-Security-Policy.
```

what should i do to make this work ? or, if there is any solution that i can use without using this datepicker, plz tell me so that i will use it  ,  thanks !

Comment: The first problem is related to CSS not being present - the second is because you do not have the correct authority to execute the code

Comment: Please read the documentation - http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H2-3 . Inline scripts are not allowed and there is no option to relax this restriction. You'll need to try other library or modify current one.

Comment: inline scripts are not allowed, its ok, but does that mean, datepicker or something related to that, cannot be used in chrome apps, there must be an alternative, can u plz tell me that ?

Comment: how does this website using datepicker, worldtimebuddy.com ? its a chrome app

Comment: You can still use the old extension manifest, which does not have these security restrictions; however, your extension may break in the future. See: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#manifest_version

Answer (score 8):

There is a simple solution: use jQuery UI **1.8.22 or newer**.

They finally fixed datepicker to not use inline javascript any more (a 4 year old bug ticket - http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/3945), solving problems with Adobe AIR, MSIE in intranet, and, yes - Chrome extensions with v2 manifest.

Answer (score 0):

As Mentioned Above You can Upgrade to 1.8.22 Or Higher or Resolve This Or You Can Use Directly One of the Required JS From the Below Location which Will also Work For You.

Assuming that You are already working with the latest version of JQuery Else Upgrade to Newer Version then You can choose any of the below or Use the Latest UI Version

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/main/ui/widgets