# Crossrider: Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval

Tags: crossrider

Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'".

I added datepicker in my crossrider crossplatform extension its opened properly but when i click on the dates of the calendar to select it gives me following error

Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'".

What i suppose to do to resolve this issue, whoever knows to resolve this issue please reply fast, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any code which make it hard to determine the exact cause, but it's likely that is due to an inline script or similar which is violating the [Content Security Policy](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html). Commonly, the issue is resolved by loading the inline code from an external file and applying it using some jQuery or equivalent.

Comment: I just followed this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12244537/2935124 answer and its worked for me, Thanks again Shlomo